# InteliJ Bookmarks window is not visible

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, intellij-15

I use IntelliJ IDEA v2021.1.3 and as mentioned on [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/bookmarks.html) page, I checked on `View | Tool Windows | Bookmarks` to view all bookmarks, but there is not any menu or opened window available as shown on the screenshot. So, is there any bug? Or how can I open bookmarks window toolbar?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bookmarks feature is new in IntelliJ 2021.3. See [*What’s New*](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/#user-experience) page.

You have to update to version 2021.3 to have that feature. If you see the page you indicated, the same is for  2021.3 version.

Your version does not have that link.

In 2021.3:

[image]

See the images bellow from https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/bookmarks.html#add-bookmarks and https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2021.1/discover-intellij-idea.html.

[image: 2021.3]
[image: 2021.1]

Answer (score 2):

You can find bookmarks in "Navigate". Also you can tap Shift twice and find any actions you want

Comment: Yes, you right, voted up. But I cannot dock this window to the bottom as the other tool windows. Do you have any idea for docking to bottom, etc?